# Formula aplicada para varias filas

Tags: excel

Estoy haciendo una formula en `excel` para restar unas celdas dependiendo de un valor lógico

```
=SI(Y(G11=DATOS!D2; B11="N2");C6-C11;0)
```

Con esta formula el valor que pongo en cantidad me resta con el numero de canvas dándome el resultado, pero esta formula solo me funciona para esa fila, estoy viendo como puedo acomodar la formula para que me funcione en el resto de filas y no solo en la fila 11, me refiero a que si pongo otros datos en la fila 12 y pongo una nueva cantidad esa cantidad también se reste en con el numero de canvas y me de el resultado en la celda C7.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En la formula estoy siendo muy especifico con los campos por ejemplo diciendo `B11="N2"` pero también necesito que `B12="N2"` y así sucesivamente con las celdas hacia abajo para que esa formula me funcione para el resto de filas.

Comment: Puedes colocar una imagen de tu excel para darnos una idea por favor. de las celdas dentro de las columnas B y G, para replicar y ver como ayudar.

Comment: @FelipeUrcia Listo amigo

Comment: C6-C11 Aqui siempre se restara de C6 porque cuando arrastres sera C7...Cx

Comment: C6 no varía el que va a variar seria C11.. C12.. C13 ya que esa cantidad se le resta con C6

Comment: Pero entonces, esta fórmula está en la celda C7 entiendo. Dices que no incluye el resto de filas. Tienes que ser más especifico. ¿Cuál seria el resultado correcto con más filas? `C6 - suma de C11+C12+C13...`? Detalla tu respuesta y se te podrá ayudar

Comment: Si tengo que adivinar, `=SI(Y($G11=DATOS!$D$2; $B11="N2");$C$6-$C11;0)` y copiás desde la fila 11 hacia todas las filas... pero la pregunta está muy poco clara. Tratá de describir qué condición se tiene que cumplir, y cuando se cumple, qué valor tiene que mostrar, y en dónde tiene que mostrar ese valor

Comment: Actualice la pregunta a ver si me logran entender mejor a lo que trato de llegar @Pollo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que tome un número inicial y le vaya restando la suma de una columna, siempre que otras 2 columnas coincidan con condiciones:

- `C6` - Número inicial (Num Canvas)
- `C7` - lugar donde va la fórmula, para mostrar el resultado
- `C11:C99` - Columna a restarle al número inicial
- `B11:B99` - Condición 1, esta columna tiene que ser `N2`
- `G11:G99` - Condición 2, esta columna tiene que ser igual a `DATOS!$D$2` (`SUBCONTRATACION` en este ejemplo)

**Fórmula en C7**:

```
=C$6 - SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO($C$11:$C$99;$B$11:$B$99;"N2";$G$11:$G$99;DATOS!$D$2)
```

Va a sumar todos los valores del primer parámetro `$C$11:$C$99`, siempre que coincidan las condiciones las condiciones del resto. En la fórmula de `SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO()` el primer parámetro es el rango a sumar, y luego vienen rango,condición,rango,condición,...etc.

> 1. Va a sumar la celda 1 de `$C$11:$C$99`, solamente si se cumple que la celda 1 de `$B$11:$B$99` es igual a `"N2"`, y solamente si la celda 1 de `$G$11:$G$99` es igual a `DATOS!$D$2`
> 2. Va a sumar la celda 2 de `$C$11:$C$99`, solamente si se cumple que la celda 2 de `$B$11:$B$99` es igual a `"N2"`, y solamente si la celda 2 de `$G$11:$G$99` es igual a `DATOS!$D$2`
> 3. ... y así sucesivamente para todas las celdas del rango.

Para más info, leer sobre la [función SUMAR.SI.CONJUNTO](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/sumar-si-conjunto-funci%C3%B3n-sumar-si-conjunto-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b).

**Captura del ejemplo**

[image: Captura de pantalla con el resultado]

- Acá está tomando `8 - 4 - 1 = 3` (`4` y `1` son las únicas que coinciden con ambas condiciones).

Answer (score 1):

luego de haber visto tu consulta, y que me digas que si funciona en el primero y luego lo demás falla, y sabiendo también que `C6` no varia, creo que tu fallo seria en esa parte.

Para que no varíe `C6` tienes que anclarlo, esto lo haces una vez seleccionada con la tecla <kbd>F4</kbd>, o en todo caso colocando los símbolo dólar `$` antes de la columna y fila.

Esto debería ayudarte.

```
=SI(Y(G11=DATOS!D2; B11="N2");$C$6-C11;0)
```

Comment: Tu aporte me es muy util pero a lo que me refiero es que si yo pongo otros datos en la fila 12 con el valor "subcontratación" no me resta como me deberia restar, en pocas palabras la formula solo me funciona para una fila